# How can I tell if a rack and panniers will work with my bike?

Tags: mountain-bike, cargo, panniers

I have a [2012 Jamis Durango Race](http://www.evanscycles.com/products/jamis/durango-race-2012-mountain-bike-ec031771) and am interested on fitting it with rear panniers at some point.  However I want to be sure that they'll be compatible.  There seem to be mounting points on the bike but I don't know if these are standard across all bikes or not.

Do panniers and bikes come with standardised fittings so that any pannier will work with any bike?  If not, is there some kind of compatibility guide for showing which panniers can be mounted on this bike?

Comment: What are your goals of adding the rack and panniers?  Touring, commuting, bringing your lunch along?

Comment: Probably mostly for bringing home the weekend shopping.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That particular bike looks like it has mounting points for a rear rack, which is the primary issue. In general, what you are looking for are the bolt holes or "braze-ons" usually just a few inches below where the seat stays connect to the seat tube, as well as ones above the rear axle on the dropout. If your bike doesn't have them, there are ways to mount a rack using various [after market kits like this](http://www.bikebagshop.com/planet-bike-rack-hardware-p-2593.html).

If you can mount a rear rack you will find that most panniers are "universal" in that they will mount to any tubular rack. There are a few pannier bags that are sold as part of a system and work only with one specific rack, so you will want to watch out for those.

The second issue will be the length of the chain stays. If the frame is somewhat compact, or if you have long feet, you may run into the problem of the back of your feet hitting the front of the bags while you pedal. This is usually only a problem on smaller frames and with larger bags like you would use for self-supported touring.

Because racks and bags change every season or two, you will likely not find a compatibility chart or site. Your best bet is to hit your Local Bike Shop and see what they have available.

Comment: Looking at the photo linked to, it does have the upper brazes for a rack.  If I'm wrong, there are collars that fit on the seat tube that will provide them.

Answer (score 3):

Be careful, you might have problems with your rear disk brake caliper interfering with rack. You might need a special rack made for this situation. Some bike models have brakes mounted between seat stay and chain stay (inside rear triangle) and can use most racks.

[image: Rack suitable for disk brakes]

See also this post: [Rack (& Pannier) for a bike with disc brakes](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/3426/rack-pannier-for-a-bike-with-disc-brakes)